# "very much" to modify verb

Tags: usage

> Die Nachricht hat mich ***_*__** überrascht.

I want to mean "the news surprised me very much".

Should I use "viel", "sehr", "sehr viel", or do all of them work?

Comment: siehe http://canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Partikel/Gradpartikel.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only one from your choices that works here is *sehr*

> Die Nachricht hat mich sehr überrascht.

*Viel* doesn't work because it's an adjective. As an adjective it only can describe a noun but does not modify a verb.

Alternatives to *sehr* (which is an adverb) are, for example, *völlig* and *total*.

> Die Nachricht hat mich völlig überrascht.
>   Die Nachricht hat mich total überrascht.

Comment: If it is a "very hard case of surprise", you can also say "..hat mich extrem überrascht."

Comment: You can also say "Die Nachricht hat mich komplett überrascht"

Answer (score 2):

With verbs you normally use "sehr": Das hat mich sehr überrascht. 
Don't use "viel" or combinations with "viel". That is uncommon. German does not use
something like "very much".

You can express a higher degree by saying Das hat mich wírklich überrascht. Here you lay stress on the first syllable of "wirklich". I indicated this by employing the sign í.